# I want to write a shell script in which I can cut a particular substring from multiple files and write it into text file

Tags: bash, shell, sh

These are the text files:

`f1.txt`:

```
TXT123456798
TRB0987906554
TXTxzcxczxzcxzc
```

`f2.txt`:

```
TXT999999999
TAB888888888
TXT777777777
```

Grep TXT from multiple files and write each cut substring with file name one by one.

I have already tried the below code:

```
#!/bin/sh


reports_count=`find /home/pverm84/folder1 -cmin -360 | grep txt | wc -l`
reports=($(find /home/pverm84/folder1 -cmin -360 | grep txt))


seq=0

while [ $seq -lt $reports_count ]
do
   echo
    CAP_reportName=${reports[$seq]}
    echo File Name is $CAP_reportName

    tbt= grep TXT $CAP_reportName | cut -c 4-6

    File1=$(basename $CAP_reportName)

    count=$tbt$File1
echo $count
        seq=`expr $seq + 1`   
done
```

Current output:

```
File name is /home/pverm84/folder1/f2.txt  
999  
777  
f2.txt  

File name is /home/pverm84/folder1/f1.txt  
123  
xzc  
f1.txt
```

Excepted output:

```
newfile.txt  
f1.txt 123   
f1.txt xzc  

f2.txt 999   
f2.txt 777
```

Comment: Where does the `newfile.txt` come from in the expected output? I assume the `f1.txt`/`f2.txt` are the file1.txt and file2.txt you describe as input, is this correct?

Comment: because I want to save the out put in new file

Comment: Tags say Bash _and_ sh, shebang says `/bin/sh`, code has bashisms. Which is it?

Comment: It is for linux

Answer (score 2):

`grep` with the `-H` flag outputs the info you want, just not in the correct format :

```
$ grep -H TXT /home/pverm84/folder1/*
/home/pverm84/folder1/file1.txt:TXT123456798
/home/pverm84/folder1/file1.txt:TXTxzcxczxzcxzc
/home/pverm84/folder1/file2.txt:TXT999999999
/home/pverm84/folder1/file2.txt:TXT777777777
```

We can use `sed` to reformat those lines :

```
$ grep -H TXT /home/pverm84/folder1/* | sed -E 's/:TXT(.{3}).*/ \1/'
/home/pverm84/folder1/file1.txt 123
/home/pverm84/folder1/file1.txt xzc
/home/pverm84/folder1/file2.txt 999
/home/pverm84/folder1/file2.txt 777
```

That `sed` command matches the `:TXTXXX...` from `grep`'s output and replaces it by the `XXX`.

You can run the command from the target directory to avoid absolute paths :

```
$ cd /home/pverm84/folder1/; grep -H TXT * | sed -E 's/:TXT(.{3}).*/ \1/'
file1.txt 123
file1.txt xzc
file2.txt 999
file2.txt 777
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/PjYRQ9).

Comment: if i need substring from 10 to 20 for that what i have to do in this regex

Comment: @Vishal I'm not sure what you mean, could you reflect that in your sample input/output?

Comment: like if i need output like this :- file1.txt 567

Comment: `cd /home/pverm84/folder1/; grep -H TXT * | sed -E 's/:TXT.{4}(.{3}).*/ \1/'` maybe? https://ideone.com/bsrjeU

Comment: Thanks its working fine one more thing if you can ans

Comment: if i need output like this :- file1.txt 123 567 can it be posible

Comment: Sure, change the sed command into `'s/:TXT(.{3}).(.{3}).*/ \1 \2/'`. The basic syntax of sed's substitution command is `s/search/replaceBy/` and if you use brackets in the search part you can refer to their content in the replaceBy part; here I match the three characters after TXT in a capturing group, match another, then match the next three in a second capturing group, then I replace by the content of the first capturing group, a space and the second capturing group

Comment: if i Want file1.txt 123 5678 four character than

Comment: Hmm, `sed -E 's/:TXT.{5}(.{7}).*(.{4})$/\1 \2/'` then : https://ideone.com/IeW3Ar